# How to set default current date in jpa for mysql

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to generate current date automatically but getting this error

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server 
version for the right syntax to use near 'CURRENT_DATE' at line 1
```

```
@Column(name = "ddate", columnDefinition = "DATE DEFAULT CURRENT_DATE")
private Date ddate;
```

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `Date`. That class is poorly designed and long outdated. Instead use `LocalDate` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend trying the [CreationTimestamp](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/annotations/CreationTimestamp.html) annotation paired with `nullable = false, updatable = false`

```
@Column(name = "ddate", nullable = false, updatable = false)
@CreationTimestamp
private Date ddate;
```

The above strategy uses the current VM date, so use this if you are ok with that.

Comment: yupe it's work for me thank you so much for this solution and if possible can you suggest me  any resource about spring data jpa and it's all annotation?

Comment: and also how  to generate sequence without primary key?

Comment: Not sure off the top of my head, might be worth to research yourself and create a new question if you get stuck. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

As a alternative to the @cjnash's answer, there is [`@CreatedDate`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/annotation/CreatedDate.html) annotation which is provided by Spring to keep track of created time of entities.

Main difference of those annotations is `@CreationTimestamp` **applicable to Hibernate only** while `@CreatedDate` **applicable to all stores covered by Spring Data: JPA, JDBC, R2DBC, MongoDb, Cassandra and so on**.

But for this to work, there are few steps to config.

1. Annotate Entity class with `'@EntityListeners'` annotation.
2. Create fields by annotating them with `'@CreatedDate'`.
3. Add `@EnableJpaAuditing` annotation to 'App' class.
   This annotation is used to enable auditing in JPA via annotation configuration.

   ```
    // Entity Class
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "my_employee")
    @EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
    public class Employee {
    .....
    .....
    @CreatedDate
    @Column(name = "ddate")
    private Date ddate;

    .....
    .....

    }

    // App Class
    @SpringBootApplication
    @EnableJpaAuditing
    public class App {
    .....
    .....
    }
   ```

Check this [example](https://self-learning-java-tutorial.blogspot.com/2019/08/spring-data-jpa-createddate.html) for more details.